# How to access EJBs in integration tests with Maven and Embedded Glassfish?

Tags: maven, ejb, integration-testing

I'm doing integration tests in my app using `maven-embedded-glassfish-plugin`. Tests work well, except the ones where I'm trying to access EJBs using JDNI. **How to access my EJBs?**

**EDIT**

I managed to get a bit closer (I think so, anyway) to success. Now I get following error:

```
xxx.xxx.ejb.__EJB31_Generated__ItemDatabase__Intf____Bean__ cannot be cast to xxx.xxx.ejb.ItemDatabase
```

using `InitialContext.lookup()`. When I try to lookup some not existing class I get "Lookup failed" error, so clearly *something* is found, but it's somehow incompatible with original EJB class...

Answer (score 0):

please feed us some more if you want proper help. E.g, are you accessing a remote or local EJB? What's the JNDI lookup string?

To my experience, there are 2 ways of running integration tests over a Glassfish embedded server.

1. pragmatically create and launch a server

   - **pros**: minimal maven configuration, full control over the folder to deploy.
   - **cons**: you are stuck with only an EJB container. No JMS, nor web nor WS.
2. run a server from the maven plugin

   - **pros**: full server running
   - **cons**: I still cannot access EJB through initial context, connection is refused. I'm asking a question in a separate thread about this.